# XAMPP Windows Apache vhosts not redirecting properly

Tags: apache, virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost

    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/">
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/gl"
    ServerName gl.dev

    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/gl">
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The above is what I currently have in my vhosts file. When I hit localhost I want my root to open, but when I load gl.dev I want the individual site to open. Any ideas?

hosts file:

```
    127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
    127.0.0.1   gl.dev
```

Comment: name-based vhosts depends on the Apache version.

Answer (score 0):

I think in windows you have to use backslash when specifying document root. please try the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName localhost
 ServerAlias *.localhost
 DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\"

 <Directory />
  #Options FollowSymLinks
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName gl.dev
 ServerAlias *.gl.dev
 DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\gl"

 <Directory />
  #Options FollowSymLinks
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart WAMP server